# Splash icon slighlty varies after app launch

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, xcode5, splash-screen

I have an application that needs to work on iOS6 and 7. I also have the required images for the splash. I have been facing a issue which I could not figure out how it occurs and the issue is when the splash screen loads,the initial image slightly changes after few seconds. Changes in the sense stretches a bit. This happens in landscape. Could someone point me out what can be the issue? Thanks in advance

Also note that I am setting the image according to orientation initially and on orientation change too. But before even the method for setting splash image is hit, there is an image already present on the screen. Where did this image come from? I even removed Launch image option from app's general settings but it still seems to assign an image by default !

Splash Landscape = 1024x768 and its @2x = 2048x1536
Splash Portrait = 768x1024 and its @2x = 1536x2048

Comment: can you add some screenshots ?

Comment: sceenshots will look similar. This change happens too fast.The noticeable change is image shows a difference of 20 pixels I guess.

Comment: In Interface Builder on tap "Size inspector" you can choose autoresize mask you want. Also in little square screen it will animation with using autoresize so you can see what option did you set.

Comment: Specify the size of the image you have for the splash in the question

Comment: @LithuT.V: I am not sure on how the image loads even before I set them initially? I guess that might be the problem. It loads an image first then when my method is called it loads the image I have and there is a flick effect, like the image feels like stretched a bit

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick responses. I didn't notice the default images in the folder which were creating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the key point that landing image are 20px short from landing mode

Splash Landscape = 1024x768 Not correct

Splash Landscape = 1004x768 Correct

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found what was going wrong. I had images named as Default.png and Default@2x.png which were portrait images in my resource folder. I deleted and removed their references but the issue persisted. So I removed them from the project and renamed the required images, reset the simulator and run. Got it fixed. I guess the Xcode 5 automatically takes the images by default from resources and loads in the Launch Images in general tab. I even removed Launch Image set in general tab.